# User account and Roles, how to implement different properties for accounts in different roles?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a Account Class like this

```
public class Account
{
    public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Role> Roles{ get; set; }

}
```

I have a Role Class Like this

```
public class Role
{
    public Guid RoleId{ get; set; }
    public string RoleName{ get; set; }
    public virtual List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

update 2

I have two different roles named Student and Teachers.
Account should have properties like Marks when it is in student role and different property when in Teacher role.
How to implement this kind of scenario.

Update

i was thinking of inheriting Account class and create student and teachers with properties related to them, but i already have roles named student and Teacher. So it will be like Student object will be in student role, that will be redundant i think

Comment: Post update, I'm have trouble seeing what your are actually asking?

Comment: Student and Teacher are two Roles...An Account is created and added to student role, that makes a student...Also An account is created and added to Teacher role. So the Account class is one, but i have properties which will be different for student account and Teacher Account...tx for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the Membership Class where users can be defined in Roles and then depending on the current login you can check if the user is in a particular role, this is defined in the database